# Andengine - Drawing Text on/in Sprites

Tags: android, text, sprite, andengine

Before I delve into some serious lowlevel debugging, I was just wondering if there was any problem with the concept of drawing text on a sprite.
Trawling through the API examples I noticed there is nowhere this is being done. All text sprites are pre-rendered into pngs
I can almost see something trying to be drawn, but only appears white flecks or lines
Any advice would be appreciated
Cheers

```java
public class Tile extends Sprite {
    private static BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private static TextureRegion mBoxTextureRegion;
    private static BitmapTextureAtlas mFontTexture;
    private static Font mFont;
    String letter;
    private Text mText;
    public int score;

    public Tile(String letter, int score, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height, mBoxTextureRegion);
        this.letter = letter;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public static void loadResources(Context context, Engine mEngine) {
        Tile.mFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        Tile.mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(Tile.mFontTexture, context, "Arial Rounded MT.ttf", 64, true, Color.WHITE);

        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(Tile.mFontTexture);
        mEngine.getFontManager().loadFont(Tile.mFont);

        Tile.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(128, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

        Tile.mBoxTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(Tile.mBitmapTextureAtlas, context, "rect3761.png", 0, 0);

        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(Tile.mBitmapTextureAtlas);

    }

    public void draw(GraphicScene scene) {
        if (letter != null) {
            this.mText = new Text(50, 50, Tile.mFont, letter, HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
            // this.mText.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
            // GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            // this.mText.setAlpha(0.5f);
            this.attachChild(this.mText);
            scene.attachChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did come across user post of a "SpriteButton", which looks like it does what you (and I) are looking to do, at:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/spritebutton-class-t7440.html

In the comments you'll notice a mention of a built-in AndEngine class called a ButtonSprite, but I have not seen any actual code that refers to it.  It may be in another branch of the AndEngine source.

Note that you'll need to create and load a font, as well as a textureregion before instantiating a SpriteButton.

I am also looking into how well the SpriteButton handles rotation.  Translation (via user touch) seems to work okay.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is a good answer. I did in fact end up making my own sprite button in the end and hence forgot about this question.
But you are right so I am marking this as an answer. What my issue turned out to be was, I assumed that any .TTF file that I could use as a font in windows would work with andEngine Text class. But it was pretty messed up. I ended up using a different font and everything worked as expected. Cheers

Comment: @Justin could you post the class and methods you used to make the text follow the sprite?